# Googleplus API emails list is undefined

Tags: api, google-plus

According to the googleplus [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) the there are many fields for the user, one example is emails.  But when I make a https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=, i don't get back the emails i have defined in my contact section under emails.  I tried making them public as well, still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

- There is a known issue where the email list will not be returned
- You can request an additional scope, userinfo.email to get a user's verified email address

The following example shows how this can be done in JavaScript:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function onSigninCallback(resp){
    console.log(resp);
    gapi.client.load("oauth2", "v2", function(){
      gapi.client.oauth2.tokeninfo(
        {'access_token' : resp.access_token}).
          execute(function(innerResp){console.log(innerResp.email);});
      });
  }
  </script>
  <body>
    <span class="g-signin"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
      data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
      data-clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      data-callback="onSigninCallback"
      data-theme="dark"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
    </span>

  </body>

<script>
 /**
  * Load the Google+ JavaScript client libraries.
  */
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/auth:plusone.js?onload=startApp';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</html>
```

An open issue, ["ability to obtain an emails list"](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=45&q=emails&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) exists in the Google+ Platform Issue tracker, feel free to star the issue or add a comment.

Comment: thank you but i already get the verified email address (`scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]`), i am interested in the emails field.  Is there an open ticket, if so do you have a link?